# Android keep saying "SD Card is mounted, do you want to change your default storage"

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, sd-card, app2sd

About two days ago, I received this notification. At first, I just click on "Change",and in setup, set default storage to SD Card. I'm using Android 4.2.2.
But, this is happening in every half hour... I rooted my phone about 2 mounts ago,installed link2sd,and created second partition on my 16Gb SD Card. Both partitions are marked as Primary and both are FAT32. It's worked very well until 2 days ago. When I receive notification about SD Storage, my whole second partition stop working. Every apps on second partition is "unreachable" and I must restart my phone.
Do you know how to "fix" this, because, my SD Card is ok,it's seems that android unmount and mount SD Card and show this notification automaticly.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, when I format whole SD Card,and delete second partition, this notification is not showing,but,again,when I create second partition, notification is shown on my home screen,and keep asking me to change default storage.

Answer (score 0):

do u still have this problem.? Did you get solution for this.?

If yes, just share how you solved it.

If no, then this following **FAQ** page 21th question will help you to find the solution.

They have said try to update your Link2SD app. That will solve your problem.

http://www.link2sd.info/faq

Comment: I have temporary solution, WakeLock keeps processor to minimum,and this message is not showing. But,every time when I reboot phone, and forgot to start wakelock app, every app on sdext2 is not working. Im trying to find permanent solution.

Comment: Do you update Link2SD to its latest version.?

Comment: Yes,it's on automatic updates list. But I'll try to reinstall the app. When i check FAQ last time,this question was not exist. I have this problem for more than 8 mounts. I'll try with reinstall,maybe the newer version will finally fix this.

Comment: Hope that will solve your problem and make my answer accepted. If still have the problem, reply me.

Comment: Try to set your SD card second partition as Non-FAT (ext2, ext3, ext4 or f2fs) file system. Because you mentioned FAT32 as your file system in question that dose not supported in UNIX (POSIX compilant) file system permissions. That will cause security breakdown of apps private data.